# Why does my mapping of <C-PageX> to :bY not work in gvim?

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc` file, I have the following two lines:

```
noremap! <C-PageDown> :bnext <CR>
noremap! <C-PageUp>   :bprev <CR>
```

but they do not work!  In insert mode, typing

```
<C-v><C-PageDown>
```

returns

```
<C-PageDown>
```

(literally) and similarly so for `<C-PageUp>` and if I try to execute the command I get

```
:bnext
```

(plus a newline).  In normal mode there's no effect.  Thus, I know that the key map isn't being gobbled up by `X` or my shell but what else could be the problem?  Other key maps work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

```
noremap  <C-PageDown>           :bnext <CR>
noremap  <C-PageUp>             :bprev <CR>
inoremap <C_PageDown> <C-\><C-O>:bnext <CR>
inoremap <C_PageUp>   <C-\><C-O>:bprev <CR>
```

In insert mode, anything on the RHS of the key mapping is inserted literally so we need to use `<C-O>` which enters normal mode for a single command.  The `<C-\>` prevents the cursor from moving leftward which occurs when invoking `<C-O>` at the end of a line.

Also note that you can't have a space between `<C-O>` and `:bnext` else it will be eaten by `<C-O>`.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, because this keys are already used by vim for switching tab pages? [See the description in vims documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#%3CC-PageDown%3E)

Comment: Well, [not according to this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_2%29) (c.f. second paragraph under Unused Keys).

Answer (score 0):

The n in :noremap is for normal mode, so it won't work in insert mode. If you want it to work in insert mode, use :imap. If you were trying to use <C-V> to make it work in insert mode, I think you were looking for <C-O>.

Comment: No. That would be `:nnoremap`; two `n`s.